# How to use Decorators with electron-prebuilt-compile?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, electron, decorator

I encountered a nasty syntax error, when trying to use decorators in an electron, react, redux project.

```
Failed to compile B:/Projekte/sketches/electron-react-get-
started/app/pages/Layout.js: B:/Projekte/sketches/electron-react-get-
started/app/pages/Layout.js: Unexpected token (7:0)
SyntaxError: B:/Projekte/sketches/electron-react-get-
started/app/pages/Layout.js: Unexpected token (7:0)
   5 | import {fetchUsers} from "../actions/userActions";
   6 | 
>  7 | @connect((store) => {
     | ^
   8 |     return {
   9 |         users: store.users
  10 |     }
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (B:\Projekte\sketches\electron-react-get-
started\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:4454:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (B:\Projekte\sketches\electron-react-get-
started\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1761:8)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseDecorator (B:\Projekte\sketches\electron-react-get-
started\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1939:10)
   at Parser.pp$1.parseDecorators (B:\Projekte\sketches\electron-react-get-
started\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1924:26)
   at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (B:\Projekte\sketches\electron-react-get-
started\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1818:10)
    at Parser.parseStatement (B:\Projekte\sketches\electron-react-get-
started\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:5910:22)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseBlockBody (B:\Projekte\sketches\electron-react-get-
started\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:2268:21)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (B:\Projekte\sketches\electron-react-get-
started\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1778:8)
    at Parser.parse (B:\Projekte\sketches\electron-react-get-
started\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1673:17)
    at parse (B:\Projekte\sketches\electron-react-get-
started\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:7305:37)
```

As I stated in the question, I run the compiling stuff trough the "electron-prebuilt-compile" package. Which comes in handy and worked fine until now.

The npm page of this package says it's compiling is empowered by "electron-compile".
electron-compile works for JS ES6/ES7 (via Babel) as stated on their 
[github page](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-compile), what makes me wonder why I encounter this "decorator" problem, as ES6 or at least ES7 comes with this feature. **See edit**

Any suggestions on how to fix this error?
Electron-prebuilt-compile doesnt let me configure the webpack.config.
Maybe I have to set up webpack myself? If I do so, how to combine it with electron?

**Edit** 
As estus stated in his answer: ES6 doesn't include decorators, but "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy" does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'ES7' is ambiguous and technically incorrect term, because it colloqually referred to proposals that weren't included into ES6 (currently as ES.next), but also had referred to ES2016.

Package description [refers to ES2016](http://][1]). While decorators are not a part of existing standards and supported in Babel via [a plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-decorators/).

[The package](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-compile#how-do-i-set-up-babel--less--whatever-the-way-i-want) explains that it respects user `.babelrc` file, so it should contain `transform-decorators` or `transform-decorators-legacy` in `presets` section, and respective Babel plugin should be installed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I already knew there was a plugin for babel to solve the issue, but I couldn't put the pieces together.
So I set up webpack and babel myself and removed electron-prebuilt-compile.
It's the same outcome in the long run, but doesn't answer the question, so I'll mark your answer as correct